# General Solution to linear Schrodingers Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to find a solution to 
$$\displaystyle \left[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 - \frac{2}{r} + C(r)\right]\phi(r) = E\phi(r)$$

where C(r) is a known function of r. I am just looking for some help on the strategy to solve explicitly for ϕ(r). I have read through the solution for hydrogen using separation of variables but

1) I don't really understand it, they make a lot of handwavy arguments 
about terms disappearing :)

2) How does one handle the extra $C(r)$?

Comment: When you first learn the Schrödinger Equation in Physics there are 'hand wavy' arguments. The important thing is that the solutions appear to be physically meaningful.

On the second or third pass of solving the SE, one uses a different type of approach which mathematically justifies the choices made with the first pass.

So my advice for you right now is the roll with it and wait for the better arguments to come.

Comment: If you are impatient for a 2nd/3rd pass approach, watch the MIT OCW lectures in 8.05 Quantum Physics II http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/

Comment: @SimonS thanks for the resources! What do you mean by "roll with it" :)?

Comment: 'roll with it': put up with the mathematically casual solution for now